# Use PHP to count images in specific subdirectories

Tags: php

I've got images stored in a directory structure a bit like this:

- images

  - foo

    - thumb

      - awefawef.jpg
      - dtyhtyh.jpg
    - full

      - awefawef.jpg
      - dtyhtyh.jpg
      - eriguherg.jpg
  - bar

    - thumb

      - erg.jpg
    - full

      - erg.jpg
      - tyjhr5g.jpg
  - some_other_dir
  - etc ...

(Note: There won't always be the same number of images in a "thumb" directory as in it's neighbouring "full" one.)

So: **I need to use PHP to count the total number of images in all of the "full" directories.**

I'm sure I could find a way to do this by getting a list of all subdirectories of "images", then cycling through them and counting the images in each one's "full" folder. But as there are going to be thousands of directories with hundreds of images in each folder, I'm looking for the most efficient solution possible - this is going to need to be done pretty often by the site.

What's the most efficient approach here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would work in the situation you've outlined:

```
$imagecount = count(glob("images/*/full/*.jpg"));
```

Comment: Wow, that is elegant - I didn't know about glob()! I just implemented and counting 20k images hardly makes an impact on page load times. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = count(glob("images/*.jpg"));

echo "In images have $count images";
```

Comment: He wanted to count the images in each `full` directory. Furthermore your answer seems copied from [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11783910/1731935)

Comment: @Manuel thanks for reply, i only now able to login to my account, my answer isn't was copied from that answer, i copied my answer from my PHP project, but it's now doesn't matter =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<?php

$directory='images';
$count=0;
$full_images='';

if($handle = opendir($directory)) {

  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

    if(is_dir($directory.'/'.$file))
    {
    if($handle1 = opendir($directory.'/'.$file."/full")) {

      while (false !== ($file1 = readdir($handle1))) {
        if(!is_dir($file1))
         {
            $count=$count+1;
        $full_images[$file]['full'][]=$file1;
          } 
      }
    }
    }
  }

closedir($handle);
}

echo "Total count images in all of the full directories in: <b>".$count."</b> <br />";

foreach($full_images as  $k => $v)
{
  foreach($v as $key)
  {
    echo "Total count images in ".$k."\'s full directory in:  <b>".count($key)."</b><br />";
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abid! I'm guessing Kolink's answer above is going to be more efficient (?) but good to see another way of doing it.